# CakePHP 3 authError message translation not working

Tags: authentication, translation, cakephp-3.0

I have an application with CakePHP 3.
My app is in french and english.

In the function initialize() of my UsersController, i said :

```
'authError' => __('Vous devez vous identifier pour accéder à cette zone.')
```

In my en_US/default.po (generated with poedit) i have :

```
#: Controller/SavsController.php:35 Controller/UsersController.php:29
msgid "Vous devez vous identifier pour accéder à cette zone."
msgstr "Login to access this area."
```

But the translation is not working... This message is always in french, why ? Anyone already had this problem ?

I set the default language to 'fr_FR' in my config, i have a generated .pot and po files for fr_FR and en_US. When i switch language in my app, all works good except this flash message...

The others message works good, ex :

```
#: Template/Pages/home.ctp:44
msgid "Accès Espace Client"
msgstr "Customer Area Access"
```

The code of my initialize function :

```
parent::initialize();
$this->loadComponent(
    'Auth', [
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'home'
        ], 'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'logout'
        ], 'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'
        ], 'logoutAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'logout'
        ],
        'authError' => __('Vous devez vous identifier pour accéder à cette zone.'), 
        'authenticate' => [
            'Cotral' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'email' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: Nobody can help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably switch the language in `beforeFilter()`, which is called *after* `initialize()`.

You can either implement your language switching logic before you load the AuthComponent, or update the value of the `authError` key in `beforeFilter`.

Comment: Both question and answer apply to CakePHP/2 as well.